# Current fill color in Processing

Tags: colors, processing

In Processing, I can call `fill(myRGBValue)`
to set a fill color.  Is there a way for me to query for the current fill color?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, [just use something like](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html):

```
int fillColor = g.fillColor;
```

`g` is the name of the default renderer. You can also get the stroke color using `g.strokeColor`. Both of these take into account `noFill()` and `noStroke()`.

Note though that will probably only work in the Java version of Processing, not P5.js which works differently under the hood.

Comment: Note: Processing is only converted to Java if run/compiled using the PDE. Browsers will run Processing source code by compiling it to JavaScript, for instance, in which case g.fillColor will not work, because there is no underlying Java framework.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hmm, I see. I admittedly never went that route. Not sure what the OP's use case is there...

Comment: Thanks, `g.fillColor` worked well. I have used it to wrap a call to `fill(newColor)` with `getOldColor` and `replaceBackToOldColor`. I am working just in Java, not exporting to javascript. But the idea of running my work as javascript is interesting - I'll go and do some research on how to run a processing file in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your program compatible, use something like:

// Utilities

```
private static color currentFillColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
private static color currentStrokeColor = 0xFF000000;

void setFill(color c)
{
  currentFillColor = c;
  fill(c);
}

color getFill()
{
  return currentFillColor;
}

void setStroke(color c)
{
  currentStrokeColor = c;
  stroke(c);
}

color getStroke()
{
  return currentStrokeColor;
}
```